# Finding Min, Max and Median for Survey program

Tags: c

A beginner C program to find minimum, maximum and average rating for Samsung s5 telephone. Ratings are 1-10.

I'm a beginner so thought this looked very simple but I ALWAYs get the wrong answer for Min, Max and Mean. I think it makes sense what I have tried but I can't see why the result doesn't return correctly. Please help.

```
//Assignment #1 Structured Programming
//Samsung Galaxy S5 Rating program
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#define SIZE 3

//Function to calculate average rating

int mean(const int rating[]);
int max(const int rating[]);
int min(const int rating[]);


int main (void)
{
    int response[SIZE];
    int count;

    for (count=0;count<SIZE;count++)
    {
        printf ("Please enter your rating for the Samsung Galaxy S5 %d\n",count);
        scanf ("%d",&response[count]);
    }
    for (count=0;count<=SIZE;count++)
    {
      printf("%d\n",response[count]);
    }

    mean(response);
    max(response);
    min(response);

    getch();
    return 0;
}

int mean(const int rating[])
{
    int average;
    int x;//counter for totalling array elements
    int total=0;//variable to hould the sum of the array elements

    for (x=0;x<SIZE;x++)
    {
         total+=rating[x];
    }
    average=total/SIZE;
    printf ("The average rating for Samsung Galaxy S5 is %d\n",average);
}
int max(const int rating[])
{
    int max;
    int x;

    for (x=0;x<=SIZE;x++)
    {
        if (rating[x]>rating[x+1])
        {
            max=rating[x];
        }        
    }
    printf ("Max rating for Samsung Galaxy S5 is %d\n",max);

}
int min(const int rating[])
{
    int min;
    int x;

    for (x=0;x<=SIZE;x++)
    {
        if (rating[x]<rating[x+1])
        {
            min=rating[x];
        }        
    }
    printf ("Min rating for Samsung Galaxy S5 is %d\n",min);
}
```

Comment: Please do indentation to your codes next time perfectly for better understanding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your mistakes are common for new learners. Your problem was in for statements and initializing the variables. Sometimes the loop was iterating 4 times and sometimes 3 times.

In loops you need to keep something in mind-

- when you make `for(i=0;i<=3;i++)` the loop iterates 4 times actually
- In declaring array you declared response[SIZE] which was a array of 3, but you were iterating the loop sometimes greater than 3
- The logic of `max()` and `min()` was not correct

Changes lines are marked at the end of line as changed

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define SIZE 3

//Function to calculate average rating

int mean(const int []);
int max(const int []);
int min(const int []);


int main (void)
{
    int response[SIZE+1];//changed
    int count;


    for (count=0;count<=SIZE;count++)//changed
    {
        printf ("Please enter your rating for the Samsung Galaxy S5 %d\n",count);
        scanf ("%d",&response[count]);
    }
    for (count=0;count<=SIZE;count++)
        printf("%d\n",response[count]);

    mean(response);
    max(response);
    min(response);
    return 0;
}

int mean(const int rating[])
{
    int average=0;//changed
    int x;//counter for totalling array elements
    int total=0;//variable to hould the sum of the array elements

    for (x=0;x<=SIZE;x++)//changed
         total+=rating[x];
    average=total/(SIZE+1); //changed
    printf ("The average rating for Samsung Galaxy S5 is %d\n",average);
}

int max(const int rating[])
{
    int max=rating[0];//changed
    int x;

    for (x=0;x<=SIZE;x++)
    {
        if (rating[x]>max)//changed
            max=rating[x];
    }
    printf ("Max rating for Samsung Galaxy S5 is %d\n",max);
}

int min(const int rating[])
{
    int min=rating[0];//changed
    int x;

    for (x=0;x<=SIZE;x++)
    {
    if (rating[x]<min)//changed
        min=rating[x];     
    }
    printf ("Min rating for Samsung Galaxy S5 is %d\n",min);
}
```

Comment: works perfect. and very simple explanation. thank you.

Comment: Next time write your code neatly by proper indentation :) @RaphaelJones

Comment: I tried. Sorry. Not sure what is considered 'neat' or 'proper indentation'.

Comment: Indentation means use tabs when you write code inside for, you see the way codes are written everywhere, they follow tabs or extra spaces before lines for easy debugging and understanding, and neat mean, don't use unnecessary enters or newlines. You understand? :) @RaphaelJones

Answer (score 3):

Here is the correct written program

```
//Samsung Galaxy S5 Rating program
#include <stdio.h>

#define SIZE 3

//Function to calculate average rating


void get_mean(const int rating[])
{
    float average;
    int x;//counter for totalling array elements
    int total=0;//variable to hould the sum of the array elements

    for (x=0;x<SIZE;x++)
    {
        total+=rating[x];
    }
    average=(float)total/SIZE;
    printf ("The average rating for Samsung Galaxy S5 is %.2f\n",average);
}

void get_max(int rating[])
{
    int maximal = rating[0];
    int x;

    for (x=0; x<SIZE; x++)
    {
        if (rating[x]>maximal)
        {
            maximal = rating[x];
        }
    }
    printf ("Max rating for Samsung Galaxy S5 is %d\n",maximal);

}

void get_min(int rating[])
{
    int minimal=rating[0];
    int x;

    for (x=0;x<SIZE;x++)
    {
        if (rating[x]<minimal)
        {
            minimal=rating[x];
        }
    }
    printf ("Min rating for Samsung Galaxy S5 is %d\n",minimal);

}

int main (void)
{
    int response[SIZE];
    int count;


    for (count = 0; count < SIZE; count++)
    {
        printf ("Please enter your rating for the Samsung Galaxy S5 %d\n",count+1);
        scanf ("%d",&response[count]);
    }
    for (count = 0; count < SIZE; count++)
    {
        printf("%d\n",response[count]);
    }

    get_mean(response);
    get_max(response);
    get_min(response);

    return 0;
}
```